# Retain values while on loop

Tags: matlab, loops, freemat

Can someone please help me to amend this so that the each values of 'c' and 'v' are stored every time the loop repeats.

```
c(1)=0;

v = 1;

timestep = 0.1;

    while c<50

        v = c*5;

        c = c+1;
    end

plot(timestep*(1:length(v)),v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's the vectorized version:

```
c = 0:50;
v = 5*c; 

timestep = 0.1;

plot(timestep*(1:length(v)), v)
```

and the looped version:

```
c = zeros(51,1);
v = zeros(51,1);

timestep = 0.1;

for ii = 1:51
   c(ii) = ii;
   v(ii) = 5*c(ii);
end

plot(timestep*(1:length(v)),v)
```

Matlab is ideally suited to go for the first solution in this sort of scenario, so I'd suggest you use the vectorized version.